# Stanford NLP training documentpreprocessor

Tags: stanford-nlp, training-data

Does Stanford NLP provide a train method for the `DocumentPreprocessor` to train with own corpora and creating own models for sentence splitting?

I am working with German sentences and I need to create my own German model for sentence splitting tasks. Therefore, I need to train the sentence splitter, `DocumentPreprocessor`.

Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

No. At present, tokenization of all European languages is done by a (hand-written) finite automaton. Machine learning-based tokenization is used for Chinese and Arabic. At present, sentence splitting for all languages is done by rule, exploiting the decisions of the tokenizer. (Of course, that's just how things are now, not how they have to be.)

At present we have no separate German tokenizer/sentence splitter. The current properties file just re-uses the English ones. This is clearly sub-optimal. If someone wanted to produce something for German, that would be great to have. (We may do it at some point, but German development is not currently at the top of the list of priorities.)